# AutoHotkey | Cannot retrieve value from Associative Array/Dictionary using key

Tags: dictionary, autohotkey, associative-array

I am trying to write a short program in AutoHotkey that will take the first character of a 4-digit code, store that in the variable `TypeChar`, then look up the matching value in the Associative Array/Dictionary called `Type` and store that value in the variable `RetrievedType`.

The problem I'm having is that when the value of `RetrievedType` is displayed after the text "Type: " in the message box, the message box only shows the predetermined text and no value of the variable. I do not know what has gone wrong but, after some testing with other strings, I believe it may be something to do with the character being interpreted as an integer rather than a string. I am really not sure though.

---

So, the code I have so far is this:

```
Type := {"1":"Alpha",  "2":"Beta", "3":"Gamma", "9":"Delta"}

p::

Code := "2xxx"

TypeChar := SubStr(Headcode, 1, 1)
RetrievedType := Type[TypeChar]

MsgBox, 0, Info, Type: %RetrievedType%
Exit
```

---

Which outputs this:

[image: Message Box where the error was discovered.]

---

Any help or solutions would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the obvious issue is that `Headcode` doesn't exist, but I'm going to assume that was just an accident when you posted the code here.

The real issue is that you're trying to access a numeric key, but your keys strings.
This is kind of a v1 limitation/issue, but not really an issue if you just *do it right*.
You can read more about it [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Keys).

So the fix is to *cast* to string e.g like this `"" 2`.
<sup>(casting doesn't really exist in AHK, but I think this is close enough)</sup>

```
Type := { "1": "Alpha"
        , "2": "Beta"
        ,  2 : "Beta2"
        , "3": "Gamma"
        , "9": "Delta" }

Code := "2xxx"

TypeChar := SubStr(Code, 1, 1)
RetrievedType1 := Type["" TypeChar]
RetrievedType2 := Type[TypeChar]

MsgBox, 0, Info, % "Type: " RetrievedType1 "`nType2: " RetrievedType2
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had to edit out a few parts of the script that weren't useful for the question and changed the names of some variables, must've forgotten to change `Headcode` to just `Code`.

Comment: Regarding your answer, it works great! Thank you so much for helping!